# ui.bootstrap.datepicker Clear button event

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

Currently using 
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker

How can I hook up the clear button so that when it is clicked, I can be notified?

I like to something like when 
Clear button clicked, change the textbox value.

Comment: Did you figure out with some solution? Because I just broadcast event from lib and handle it in my code. My solution is not a piece of good code.

Answer (score 2):

How about if you apply $watch on the model your date is attached to?

```
$scope.$watch('dt', function(){
    //do something
});
```

Since once the Clear button is triggered, it will affect the model.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at "edit in plunkr" on the link you provided? The code is super easy...

HTML

```
<datepicker ng-model="dt"></datepicker>
<button type="button" ng-click="clear()">Clear</button>
```

JS

```
$scope.clear = function () {
    $scope.dt = null;
    // do something else...
};
```

Comment: I dont think i can add the ng-click

Comment: using as the datepickerPopup

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the answer above, you can detect that Clear has been clicked by using `$scope.$watch` as follows:

```
$scope.$watch('dt', function(newValue, oldValue) {
   if (newValue=== null) {
      // Clear has been clicked
   }
});
```